# Get all combination without repetition

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
        Dim combinations As New List(Of String)

        Dim word As String = "abc"

        For c1 = 0 To word.Length - 1
            combinations.Add(word(c1))
            For c2 = 0 To word.Length - 1
                If c2 <> c1 Then
                    combinations.Add(word(c1) & word(c2))
                    For c3 = 0 To word.Length - 1
                        If c3 <> c2 And c3 <> c1 Then
                            combinations.Add(word(c1) & word(c2) & word(c3))
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

The output:

```
a, ab, abc, ac, acb, b, ba, bac, bc, bca, c, ca, cab, cb, cba
```

How to make a function, which would do the same thing for unlimited word length?

Comment: Q: Homework?  Suggestion: Google "vb.net permutation" :)

Comment: There is a very efficient way of making all combinations when there is a limit (high enough, to be sure) on the number of letters, say, a 32 or 64.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't know how this combinatorics type is called. It's not the usual permutation or combination type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a vb.net coder, but saw this an interesting exercise.  Here my answer in pseudo code:

```
array A = ('a','b','c') //add all the unique letters to an array
integer COUNT = length of A
array P = A //initialize P (the final answer) as A
array L = A //initialize L as A to start
for j=2 to COUNT {
  array N = () //new empty array
  foreach i in L { //loop through all the elements of L
     foreach m in A { //loop through all the elements of A
        if (i does not contain m) { 
          push (i + m) into P //push the concatenation of i & m into array P
          push (i + m) into N //do the same thing for array N the next loop through
        }  
     }
  }
  L = N 
}
change P to a string or whatever you want the output to be....
```

Comment: Firefox and/or javascript break over 10... 10 letters have 9864100 Permutations (without repeating letters and with variable word lengths)

Answer (score 0):

[Backtracking](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch19.html) is a good way to do this. Basically, you build up a graph of the various inputs as you go, adding the next available one until you run out, then backing up and removing one, and replacing it with another. Here's [another explanation](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/392/lectures/week8/).